# AWS: 502 BadGateway: On Launching "more like this " Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, http-status-code-502

I have a Kali Linux EC2 instance hosting an Apache and Tomcat website with MariaDB which was configured with a Route53 URL

This was running fine, I then did

**EC2** > **Action** > **Image and Template** > **Launch more like this**

To create a copy instance of production instance to work on some bugs in production.

This started one more instance.
However, I started getting the 502 error on using the production URL.

I also noticed that an application load balancer was created (I do not remember asking for it to be created)

Thanks,
Sunil.

Answer (score 0):

Got it
I guess when i cloned the instance. It shutdown the services of apache tomcat and mariadb

hence the error 502 as Route 53 was pointing to a dud server ( However I would have associated 502 with some misconfiguration)

Once i checked the services on the server which were all down
ps -ef |grep http
ps -ef |grep tomcat
ps -ef |grep db

It was just a question of starting them in right sequence.

Thanks a ton for being around. Just knowing that there are helpful people at my back makes a lot of difference.

This was my first question hope to contribute many more.

Sunil
[www.onelife.in](http://www.onelife.in)